# How to create an automatic Revision History table in Word 2007

Tags: ms-office, word-2007

Is it possible in Word 2007 to create a revision history table automatically using track changes or some other method?

e.g.

**Revision History**

DateVersionDescriptionAuthor
16/09/20081.0CreatedJohn Smith
17/09/20081.1Fixed dumb spelling errorsColin Jones

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Automating it would require VBA and macros, so yes it is programming related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do automatically.

I'd suggest that you keep track manually with a table like you suggested, and then keep all your documents in a version control system under a separate documentation branch in order to have an automatic revision history. If you feel up to it, you could also create a tool that compares said element to the revision history of the document and shouts at you if you haven't updated it :)

Answer (score 0):

It is really a serendipity as I was grappling with the exact same issue a few days back. Although the approach I used was manual, it was quite intuitive.

There is an option to compare documents in word 2007 in the review tab.You can choose to generate a new document with only the changes. Open the change document on a second moniter and manually incorporate changes.

You can also go to Print and select printing the markup in the new document( if present) but as even the most trivial of changes generate a new entry, it becomes difficult to get to the meat of the changes.

Hope this helps.